# how to turn off "warning treaded as error" in visual studio for mac

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I have the following error when I use the visual studio for mac, and I want to turn off this feature. There is no such option in `Solution Explorer > Options > Builds`

> .../Serialization.cs(27,27): Error CS0219: Warning as Error: The variable `xmlBuildOption' is assigned but its value is never used (CS0219) (FoundationBase)

[image]

Comment: You are looking at the Solution Options, you need to look at the Project Options for the Project that you want to turn off that option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Project Options`** / `Build` / `Compiler`

Last item on that property page is "Treat warning as errors"

[image]

Comment: I have only "general" and configuration" options. please check newly added picture.

Comment: @gunesmes You are looking at the Solution Options, you need to look at the Project Options

Comment: I found it in project options but it still gives the same error.

Comment: I have many projects under solutions so I needed to do it for every project. It would be nice to have if we could do it for solution. thanks this solves the problem