# Manual Provisioning for xamarin iOS app in Visual Studio not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

While working on a Xamarin ios app, publishing an archive upon selecting manual provisioning gives the following error:

"Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying await operation. "

Comment: The message appears because you are calling an async method without using `await`. This is a warning and not an error. Maybe you activated compiler option ["Treat warnings as errors"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41096600/4739420) for your build configuration that uses the manual provisioning profiles?

Comment: Hi, do u mean [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows#build-and-submit-your-app) has a problem ?

Comment: yes, I am not able to create a ipa as this warning comes and operation is not completed

Comment: @sver Okey, do you use vs for mac or vs for pc to select manual provisioning file ?

Comment: I am using vs for mac